Error building C++ code on MacOS using CMake. Error with Cocoa and Foundations
I am trying to build a cross platform application on MacOS which is written in C++. In my CMake I've included
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(lel LANGUAGES C CXX)

if(APPLE)
    enable_language(OBJC)
endif()

In my .cpp file I've also included this:
#if defined(SDL_PLATFORM_MACOS)
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h>

The error I get is the following:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:9:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:601:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSString, Protocol;

I know the reason is that MacOS uses Objective C to build programs and the codebase is C++. But I don't know how to get around this issue. I've tried to wrap my includes with
#ifdef __OBJC__
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h>
#endif

But it just causes errors saying it can't identify any of the 'Types' which would have been included from the includes.
How do I get around this issue? Thanks in advance.

Worth taking a look at what glfw does. Since they handle this exact type of dilemma in their CMake code:
https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt

Could you clarify why in project written in C++ you are including Objective-C headers? How C++ should work with NSString for example?

If you want to code objective-c or include objective-c headers in a C++ file, you need to rename the .cc or .cpp file extension to .mm.

In my .cpp file I've also included this:
#if defined(SDL_PLATFORM_MACOS)
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h>


You're including objective-c headers in a c++ file. I recommend following the link in this stackoverflow answer
